# Unhandled error in Defered when printing variable

Tags: python-2.7, twisted

Im trying to run this line of code:

```
    def __init__(self, players, loot):
    self.players = players
    self.state = MATCH_STATE_ACTIVE
    self.pendingShutdown = False
    self.shutdownTime = 0
    self.timer = LoopingCall(self.update(self))
    self.timer.start(0.07)
    self.match_id = 5
    self.playerloot = []
    self.boxloot = []
    self.loot = loot
    print("match [%d]" % self.match_id)
```

this is throwing a

```
Unhandled error in deferred
```

I have narrowed down the issue and I know for a fact the error occurs in:

```
print("match [%d]" % self.match_id)
```

when trying to print any variable. Error only occurs in this file, as other .py files ar able to print variables.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was caused by running

```
self.timer = LoopingCall(self.update(self))
self.timer.start(0.07)
```

too early, these two lines MUST be place at the end of **init** as well as removing (self) in looping call, so replace with 
LoopingCall(self.update)

```
def __init__(self, players, loot):
self.players = players
self.state = MATCH_STATE_ACTIVE
self.pendingShutdown = False
self.shutdownTime = 0
self.match_id = 5
self.playerloot = []
self.boxloot = []
self.loot = loot
print("match [%d]" % self.match_id)
self.timer = LoopingCall(self.update)
self.timer.start(0.07)
```